# Geospatial Indexing returning empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've build a sample node.js REST api, which stores users and their location in mongodb, using mongoose scheme:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
         email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
         firstName: { type: String },
         lastName: { type: String },
         loc: {
            type: [Number],  // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
            index: '2d',      // create the geospatial index
            default: [0,0]
         },
         profileImage: { type:  String },
         created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      },
     { collection: 'User' }
);
UserSchema.index({email : 1}, {unique:true});
var UserModel = mongoose.model( 'User', UserSchema );
exports.UserModel = UserModel;
```

If I add some dummy data and then query all users, using code below:

```
UserModel.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
        return res.json(400, err)
    }
    return res.json(200, users);
})
```

I get this results:

[image]

However, I want to get users within the area of 30km.
Query below always returns an **empty** array even though they all have same coordinates [0,0].

```
    UserModel.findById(req.userID, function (err, current) { 
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                status: "false",
                result: {message: "Error occurred when fetching user"}
            })
        }

        // Set max distance to 30 km
        var maxDistance = 30;

        // we need to convert the distance to radians
        // the raduis of Earth is approximately 6371 kilometers
        maxDistance /= 6371;

        UserModel.find({loc: {$near: current.loc, $maxDistance: maxDistance }}, function(err, users) {
          if (err) {
              console.log("tu" + err);
            return res.json(500, err);
          }

          return res.json(200, users);
        })
    })
```

Comment: Is your $near a GeoJSON ? if $near is a GeoJSON, the units of maxDistance are metters.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Hi :). They all have the same coordinates, so I think it shouldn't matter if it is in meters or km (for given example).